# Oozie Web Console working very slow

Tags: cloudera, oozie, hue, cloudera-cdh

In my cluster Oozie web console is very slow. When I go to the web console it takes 10 -15 secs to pass the request to oozie server and takes another 10-15 secs to publish the result got from oozie server. The same is working fine in Hue.

Has any one experienced this? Am getting this issue in both CDH 4.4 and CDH 5.0.0 beta2.

I guess there could be issues in oozie tomcat war file. Any idea guys?

Comment: How many workflows/coordinators/bundles do you have? 
Do you see anything strange in oozie-instrumentation.log?
Have you checked oozie server log?

Answer (score 0):

Often the bottleneck for Oozie is it's internal database - Derby. It works well with small installations, but not if you have dozens of coordinators with hundreds of materializations.
I recommend you to setup external database for Oozie (Postgres/MySQL/..). Cloudera provided some instruction on the subject - http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.5.1/Cloudera-Manager-Enterprise-Edition-Installation-Guide/cmeeig_topic_5_3.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, slowness was mainly caused by web server's attempts to resolve PTR record of my workstation.
Just found a lot of queries in tcpdump output upon every oozie web-console refesh:

```
12:57:28.184046 IP 192.168.1.2.33789 > 192.168.3.4.53: 18890+ [1au] PTR? 6.5.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (55) 
12:57:28.184408 IP 192.168.3.4.53 > 192.168.1.2.33789: 18890 Refused- 0/0/1 (55)
```

where

```
192.168.1.2 - oozie server
192.168.3.4 - dns server
192.168.5.6 - workstation (PTR? 6.5.168.192.in-addr.arpa. )
```

So I just created PTR for 192.168.5.6

I also have this record in /etc/hosts of workstation:

```
127.0.0.1   extjs.com
```

Otherwise, browser waits for extjs.com for some time, as workstation/dns has no internet access (127.0.0.1 rejects everything on TCP 80 / 443).